# Assigning a new value to a dataframe cell using df.loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

Can someone please tell me what the right syntax would be to do the following:

```py
dfpollution3.loc(max(dfpollution3.index),'newhospinextday') = 10
```

I get the following error:

```py
    dfpollution3.loc(max(dfpollution3.index),'newhospinextday') = 10
    ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call
```

Comment: the name of the dataframe is dfpollution3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are using the incorrect brackets, and you should use `at` not `loc` in this case.

`dfpollution3.at[max(dfpollution3.index),'newhospinextday'] = 10`

Indexing is done with square brackets [], and function calls are with parentheses ().